# Unknown beach in California

Tags: identify-this, beaches, california, northern-california

I am planning a road trip along the coast from Portland to San Francisco.

I read about a small secluded beach somewhere between Fort Bragg California and San Francisco (I think).

I google mapped it and thought it was a beautiful location for a picture.

So I quickly typed a note about the locations name......but I typed it wrong!!!

Now I can not find the location or remember what the name was, and google correction algorithm is not helping!

Please help me if you can.

I typed down the locations name as "Hear Gulch" but I remember it actually being something like Heard Gulch or something. Please help me determine the correct name if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hearn Gulch beach, California?

http://www.californiabeaches.com/beach/hearn-gulch-beach/

Comment: You were only out by one letter!